# Fetch fields dynamically from API in SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, api, dictionary, completion

I have a response from API that has a dynamic field.

```
[{"details": { "amount": "11"},
  "wallet":"MAIN"},
 {"details": { "bonus": "12"},
 "wallet":"POKER"}]
```

I want to be able to access the ,,details`` field of each object.
I tried

```
if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? Array<[String: Any]> { 
completion(.success(jsonObject))}
```

Comment: You could model the details object as a struct conforming to decodable with optional members like `let amount: Int?` and `let bonus: Int?` and then use the `JSONDecoder.decode` method.

Comment: How dynamic is the content of "details", can it contain many values or only one key/value pair? Is the type of the value always string?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, it can contain many values but the type is always String. The solution has to be able to handle new fields, if it will be added, without changes in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution here is to use `Codable` and to create a struct that contains a dictionary for the "dynamic" part

```
struct Response: Decodable {
  let details: [String: String]
  let wallet: String
}
```

and then decode it using `JSONDecoder`

```
do {
  let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Response].self, from: data)
  print(result)
  //...
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `Codable`

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let details: Details
    let wallet: String
}

// MARK: - Details
struct Details: Codable {
    let amount, bonus: String?
}
```

---

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self,from:data)
print(res)
```

Comment: I have another call from API that tells me what field shoud I handle from ,,details`` . It looks like    `{"wallet" : "MAIN", "field": "free"}, {"wallet": "POKER", "field": "bonus"}, {"wallet": "MAIN", "field": "amount"}`